# three js particles flashing image

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, gpgpu, particle-system

I have created a star animation, using `THREE.js`, a particle system, and "GPGPU". This can be seen at https://tuqire.github.io/text-stars/. However I am having a few issues with it.

There are essentially two bugs that I cannot quite understand. They are:

1) When you type some letters, some "stars" will flicker as they animate.

2) There is a weird grid on the letters where the stars will not go.

I gather the issue might be with my shaders (I am by no means a WebGL expert).

Below is my fragment shader (simplified):

```
uniform sampler2D starImg;
uniform sampler2D tColour;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec4 colour = texture2D(tColour, vUv).rgba;
    gl_FragColor = colour * texture2D(starImg, gl_PointCoord);
}
```

`vUv` value is defined in the vertex shader and is simply `position.xy`.

I create my particle system as so:

```
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for (let i = 0; i < this.numParticles; i++) {
    const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = (i % tWidth) / tWidth;
    vertex.y = Math.floor(i / tWidth) / tHeight;        
    geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
}

this.particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, this.material);
this.particles.frustumCulled = false;
```

Can anyone direct me as to where I might be going wrong, or what is missing? It would be greatly appreciated by a budding WebGL developer.

Particles rendering call:

```
this.positionFBO.simulate();
this.sizeFBO.simulate();
this.sizeFBO.simulationShader.uniforms.tPosition.value = this.material.uniforms.tPosition.value = this.positionFBO.getCurrentFrame();
this.material.uniforms.tSize.value = this.sizeFBO.getCurrentFrame();
```

I'm using this library for the fbo calculations: https://github.com/tuqire/three.js-fbo

Comment: Could you provide some information on how you are rendering the particles as well? i.e., the draw calls?

Comment: @KylonTyner added the rendering function - note I am using this lib for fbo calculations https://github.com/tuqire/three.js-fbo.

Comment: I don't seem to see either of the bugs you mention. Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84